# I don't get this case of SAML request

Tags: saml

At my job, there's a SAML authenticator provider. Just by curiosity I openned the devTools of my browser to follow the saml sequence during the authentication periode. Was expecting something like :

- The server send me a SAML Request and is certificate.
- My browser ask me what certificate he should use to authenticate me.
- My browser send informations to server.
- Server recognize me and sent me a token to allow the access of service.

But The truth is slighty different of what I expected. In fact according to my web browser :

- The server redirect me to the SAML authentication server with a GET request containing some arguments :
  [SAML Before cert selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxdNs.png)
- My browser ask me what certificate he should use.
- My browser change header of my the request above and got a response from server and the server redirect me to my service. I'm now identified :
  [SAML After cert selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JD21b.png)

So here come some questions :

- 1 : How the server autenticate me without receive information about me ?
- 2 : What my browser did  with the certificate he select ?
- 3 : what's is the SAMLRequest and RelayState args ?
- 4 : Why before selecting any certificate my request have a "provisional headers" then he get a token before getting any response ?

hope you guys could response to my questions.

Thanks in advance,

Best regard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, in case of SAML the IdP sends an assertion about the authenticated user to the SP.

How the actual authentication happens at the IdP happens is out of scope.

about 1/2: When you accessed the IdP, it might be configured to use 'TLS client auth' to perform 'auto-login'. As your browser participated in 'TLS client auth', the IdP knows about you (or better about the certificate presented).

about 3: SAMLRequest request parameter is the deflate encoded SAML AuthnRequest as HTTP redirect binding is used ... please check SAMLv2 spec. RelayState request parameter holds the target URL the SP will redirect to after successful 'SP-initaited SSO' flow.

Comment: Thanks ! it help me a lot